# wrong format to convert to a double, looks ok to me any idea?

Tags: c#, conventions

keep getting error saying string in wrong format, it looks right to me.
anyone know what's wrong with it?

```
var pound = donation.Text;
        // convert euro to pound
       var euro = (Convert.ToDouble(dontaion_euro.Text));
        var convertion_rate = 0.83;
        var converted = euro * convertion_rate;
```

**solved with**

```
 dontaion_euro.Text = "00.00";

            var euro = Convert.ToDecimal(dontaion_euro.Text);
            var convertion_rate = Convert.ToDecimal(00.83); 
            var converted = euro * convertion_rate;
```

Comment: What's in dontaion_euro.Text when you try and convert?

Comment: what is the value in dontaion_euro.Text?

Comment: text box, a number is put into it

Comment: Is your culture set to use commas instead of periods (or vice versa) for the decimal point?

Comment: Duh, what does the value look like?

Comment: if you debug and look at the value, show what it is exactly, not what you expect it to be

Comment: Humor us with an example.

Comment: if i run brake point it shows number i input eg 77

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get this error if `dontaion_euro.Text` is not a valid number.
I'd suggest you validate the inputs before you use them in calculations.
I'd suggest you use specific type if you could when you know the types in advance.

This example shows how to validate an input

```
// Parse currency value using en-GB culture. 
value = "£1,097.63";
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
// Displays:  
//       Converted '£1,097.63' to 1097.63.
```

Source: [MSDN-TryParse Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).